# Azure SQL trigger for Functions not triggering after being idle

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an isolated C# Function App running on dotnet 7 using the consumption plan with a `SqlTrigger` function. The function is relatively simple and I'm using the default settings for the `host.json`. I noticed that once my function app becomes idle the `SqlTrigger` no longer seems to trigger on new changes.

For testing I've calling a `HttpTrigger` on the Funtion App to force it to leave its idle state and almost directly the `SqlTrigger` becomes active and performs its intended actions. However I can't rely on any `HttpTrigger`'s to have the functions app leave its idle state. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-trigger) I also couldn't find any information on adjusting its polling algorithm, although its references to the consumption plan seem to suggest it should support it.

How can I have my `SqlTrigger` function as intended?

---

Edit: Checking the database logs I can also see that the particular query to retrieve its last sync version is not called for 12+ hours till I forced the Function App out of its idle state.

Comment: Do you have "Enable change tracking on the database" and  "Enable change tracking on the "wanted" table" ?

Comment: @DA yes. And the function works as intended showing that the code and configuration are valid after the `HttpTrigger` takes it out of its idle state.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reaching out to us. I understand that your SQL Trigger function app is not being triggered after it goes to idle state. Here are a few suggestions which you can try:

1. Since your app is on Consumption plan the cold start issues are bound to happen. Please check if it is feasible for you to leverage the [Dedicated (App Service)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan) plan which has [**AlwaysOn**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan#always-on) feature. Alternately you could also move the function app to the [Premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal) which has the warm execution environment that can reduce cold starts.
2. You could try to leverage the Azure Functions' [TimerTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) and schedule it to run at regular intervals (like every 5 minutes) inorder to have the function up and running.
3. You can also try adjusting the [functionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) setting for your function app. For consumption plan the default and minimum timeout is 5 min. The maximum timeout that can be set is 10 mins. This can be added to the hosts.json. Alternatively, you can also add this in the Function's app settings like:

> **AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout = 00:10:00**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Option 2 seems to work as workaround. Option 1 would be a huge increase in costs so it is not an option. Option 3 is only for setting the timeout for a function execution so it won't help with the function going to idle as executions are typically <1 sec for me.